# Windows server 2008 R2 workgroup computers have complete server access. How to restrict this?

Tags: windows, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, shared-folders, private-network

I am not a network engineer, however I can see that in our current office setup, the organization server is connected to multiple desktops in a private network. The desktops are visible in the server network window.

I am trying to make some modifications to access groups. Some of the folders in the server are shared with everyone. We can easily remove access to Everyone from the folder properties in Sharing tab. However, we need to restrict access to a shared folder only to certain computers and give access to some others in the private network (all users from those computer).

Could someone please point me to how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Access rights are given by user or group of users, not by computer. In the sharing tab, you can add/remove users or groups of users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Server 2008R2. Access control is primarily user-based – when files are accessed on behalf of a user, then it's not *machines* that log in to the server, it's users, and if you log in to the server as user account A, you get the rights that user A is supposed to have.

If you have Active Directory, you may be able to use the "device claims" feature in [Dynamic Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn408191(v=ws.11)), but this requires **Server 2012** as the absolute minimum (and even Server 2012 is EOL! that's how out of date you are), as well as making sure that Kerberos is used for all file-server access (i.e. *no* lazy IP-address based `\\1.2.3.4` file share access; computer names only).

If you *don't* have Active Directory, you cannot do this at all; non-AD file share access is always user-account based.